# How to know MX record details of a subdomain or destination server to which emails are routed in a case co-existent of two service provider

Tags: routing, mx-record, dns-zone

In case of two co existent service email provider for one domain. How can i know the mx record of a destination server if I don't know the details of a subdomain. Are there any tools to detect the mx record of a sub domain or destination server where the mails are routed by just knowing the name of public main domain name?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly.

Let's assume you have a domain `example.com` with a corresponding MX record.

If your question is how to learn about the MX record for a subdomain  "sub.example.com" then there are two possibilities:

- You query it sucessfully: `dig mx sub.example.com`.
- You don't get a result for this query.

In the latter case, you can't do anything else as it is entirely possible that their complete internal mail routing is meant to kept hidden and everything should be routed via the main MX gateway from the outside.

Comment: Thanks Sven. You understood this correctly. But my challenge is how to get the name of the sub domain where the MX record for other service provider is added.